# Windows 7 cannot find any WiFi networks

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have Windows 7 Home Premium in my Sony VAIO. Yesterday after installation of SecureW2 TTLS it stopped to find any WiFi networks. I uninstalled SecureW2 TTLS also but problem remains still.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a System Restore Point to go back to before you installed the software.

Type "System Restore" into the start menu and follow the instructions on the screen making sure to choose a date before the software was installed. Chances are it left a driver or registry setting somewhere.